# MySQL workbench, export results of select from view to JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having a bit of an issue with running an export job on mysql data.

We use a phone vendor that installed a database for all of their data, and we now have to pull some of that data for CSR metrics.

I've put together a query that selects from joined tables and inserts into a table I've created on the test database, and this calculates those metrics. However, the database connection/user overall has restrictive permissions so I can't dump or write to an outfile on this database.

I've also created a view from this query that I can select from, rather than just pulling the updated table.

I have to run a job every 15 minutes to put the totals from the CSRs into a JSON file to upload elsewhere. I'm not exactly sure how to do that, but I feel like I first need to figure  out how to clone this data to our production database on another connection.

In short, I need to take read only database info and get it to my write permissions database so that I can somehow get a job together that will update a JSON file every 15 minutes.

Is there a way to get this data 'cloned' to our other database, essentially? I can updated with any necessary information, but I don't know what would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar task: moving data from a read-only database into database with write permissions, and my solution was to write a SQL script processor (in Python) that can connect to both databases and either copy data directly from one to another or export data to CSV (or JSON) files and then import from there to the R/W database.  If running this process from a SQL script fits into your workflow, you can get the script processor here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql.  Documentation is here: http://pythonhosted.org/execsql/.  See the COPY, COPY QUERY, EXPORT, and EXPORT QUERY metacommands.